# Uninstalling a software installed via Terminal

Tags: command-line, uninstall

How to uninstall a software which I have installed via Terminal.

I have recently installed the Realtek High Definition Driver which is now a big mess with my audio system. After installed that software all the sound channels were set to mute by default (as mentioned in the installation manual).

Now I am unable to open alsamixer. I have installed alsamixer-gui. It open the some window but I am unable to adjust the controls.

I want to remove the above mentioned software and I want to set my audio system to previous state.

Can somebody suggest me how to carry out uninstallation.

Thanks in advance
Srinivas

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 4):

How did you install it ? From your question I assume from source.

If you are lucky, simply

```
sudo make uninstall
```

But if that does not work, you would then need to manually delete the files you installed.

One potential problem would be if you installed from source, you may have over written system libs, and so would need to reinstall them as well.

In the future I would advise you try to make a .deb, with checkinstall

[Ubuntu wiki checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)